AWS RDS MySQL is in private subnet, how to accessible RDS from my local machine
I am having EC2 instances in private subnet and its under NAT gateway and AWS RDS MySQL is public accessible. EC2 and RDS are in same VPC with same region.
I need to avoid AWS RDS on public accessible so created RDS using private subnet. If i created, I must able to connect with RDS on necessary time.
So, I have tried to do site to site VPN for this but my tunnelling is always down.
Please provide solution for my scenario and apart from that site to site VPN, if we have best solution for our scenario, you could suggest us.
Tried site to site VPN but tunnelling status is always DOWN.
Tried to add security group for RDS which is on private subnet, unable to connect that database with MySQL workbench on my local machine
Expecting better solution for my scenario. If site to site VPN is better solution means then need to know how to resolve tunnelling status to DOWN.

Side-note: Since your Amazon RDS database is in a private subnet, it should be set to Publicly Accessible = No. This means the DNS name will always return a private IP address.

With VPN, you need to set up Client VPN endpoints, see here how to set up Client VPN endpoints . Keep in mind to assign the VPN connection to one of the private subnets and allow the traffic to the AWS RDS database in its security groups.
Do not forget to check the costs for Client VPN.
As an alternative, you can set up a bastion host in the private network with SSM to connect to your databases. See how to access a bastion host by using Session Manager and Amazon EC2 Instance Connect .
When setting up an EC2 instance as bastion host, you can use port forwarding to your RDS database. Example command you can use locally:
aws ssm start-session --target <EC2-instance-ID> --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost --parameters '{"portNumber":["3306"], "localPortNumber":["3306"]}' --profile <your-profile>

Please, replace <EC2-instance-ID>, <your-profile>, and optionally the ports (3306) accordingly.
Side note: you can start and stop your bastion host whenever you need it to save costs.

Using Session Manager with Port Forwarding will still require an EC2 instance in the VPC to 'forward' the traffic to the RDS database. Instead of using AWS-StartPortForwardingSession you will need to use AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost. See: Start a session - AWS Systems Manager

Thanks for the hints! I updated my answer with the corrected command and the info, that the bastion host is an EC2 instance.

@Christian Banfi, Thanks for your suggestion, tried the System manager port forwarding by referring your command and  also following below link. (https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/mt/use-port-forwarding-in-aws-systems-manager-session-manager-to-connect-to-remote-hosts/)
I am getting error while trying shared command An error occurred (TargetNotConnected) when calling the StartSession operation: i-0c0e3d09900518 is not connected.  If i try to access EC2 alone using the below command
aws ssm start-session --target  i-0c0e3d09900518 getting same error.

@subhas the most obvious reason would be that the ec2 instance is not yet running. It may take some time (less than one minute usually) to be able to connect to the instance. Otherwise there can be some reasons (missing ssm agent, wrong operating system on the ec2 instance, missing permissions, ...) for that error. You may check this documentation for setting up the session manager: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started.html

Hi @ChristianBanfi, Now i am facing different error. Eventhough had "AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore" and VPC endpoints. Still connect button is not visible on that EC2 instance. Any suggestion?

@subhas can you provide the error that you get when using aws cli to connect to the ec2 instance?

@ChristianBanfi, i am not getting any error on amazon console UI. what i m facing is eventhough provided AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore role and vpc endpoints. And then mapped role to Ec2 instances(window). Still i could see connect button enabled on Ec2 instance

@subhas please, try this command locally: aws ssm start-session --target  i-0c0e3d09900518 again. There must be some error returned.
